# Try/catch doesnt work in my function Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to handle errors, because i want to redirect the user if $apimodel variable is null or other errors. Like authentication errors with the api and more. Here is my code:

```
$integration = Integration::where('name', 'lightspeed')->first();

    $apimodel = Apimodel::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('integration_id', $integration->id)
        ->where('active', true)
        ->first();

    try {
        $api = new WebshopappApiClient(
            $apimodel->data01,
            $apimodel->api_key,
            $apimodel->api_secret,
            $apimodel->data02);
    } catch (ErrorException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return view('integrations.lightspeed.index', compact('api'));
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You also did not explain what "doesnt work" exacly means.

Comment: Well, does the WebshopappApiClient class throw exceptions upon failure?

Comment: @Qirel Yes it does, it throws exceptions at failure

Comment: Apparently it does not. Show its implementation. Also, what is the fully qualified name for the `ErrorException`

Comment: @zerkms use Whoops\Exception\ErrorException;

Comment: Is there a leading slash before `Whoops`? Or is it relative to the current namespace? And show the `WebshopappApiClient` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should not (and cannot) catch Whoops exceptions, as they are automatically thrown *later* in the request lifecycle, when there is an originating exception.

[`\Whoops\Exception\ErrorException`](https://github.com/filp/whoops/blob/master/src/Whoops/Exception/ErrorException.php) extends PHP's `\ErrorException`, that's the one thrown by WebshopappApiClient, and the one you should catch. Maybe even the widest `\Exception`, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be not using correct Namespace for the exception you want to catch. As all you want to `die()` I suggest you simply catch `\Exception` Instead

```
 } catch (\Exception $e) {
   ...
```